# NextJS CredentialsProvider only returns { email }

Tags: authentication, next.js

this is my first post here on stackoverflow! I'm a beginner in web development.

I'm creating a web application with the NextJS framework.

And I am using NextAuth to authenticate users with data on my database.
But when I return my fetched user from the database with authorize function, this is what I get.
[returned object when user logged in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/047k4.png)

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'
import { compare } from 'bcryptjs'

import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

export const authOptions = {
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            type: 'credentials',
            async authorize(credentials, req) {
                const dbUser = await prisma.users.findUnique({
                    where: {
                        email: credentials.email,
                    },
                })
                if (!dbUser) return null
                if (dbUser) {
                    console.log('user found : ', dbUser)
                    const checkPassword = await compare(credentials.password, dbUser.password)
                    console.log(' — checkPassword : ' + checkPassword)
                    if (checkPassword && dbUser) {
                        console.log('credentials OK, user logged in')
                        console.log('lastDbUser', dbUser)
                        return dbUser
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new Error('Invalid credentials')
                }
            },
        }),
    ],
    pages: {
        signIn: '/connexion',
    },
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

[here is my user fetched from the database in dbUser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Ofi.png)
and i'd like to get this in the session.user

thanks !

I tried the session strategy 'jwt' in options, but no success.

I also saw the callbacks options but in didn't really understand it, if someone can explain it ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Oveflow! Please, don't post images of data, rather post the data itself. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)